# How do I add a gradient to a TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, border, textfield, gradient, flutter-design

I'm just learning flutter. Is it possible to do this in textField ?  I can't find it. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zI16v.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible You need to use 2 Containers

```dart
Container(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
          1.0,
        ),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          child: TextFormField(),
          decoration: AppColors.kInnerDecoration
              .copyWith(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
        ),
      ),
      decoration: AppColors.kGradientBoxDecoration.copyWith(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
    )
```

```dart
static var kInnerDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
  );

  static var kGradientBoxDecoration = BoxDecoration(
    gradient: themeGradient,
    border: Border.all(
      color: AppColors.whiteColor,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
  );
```

Output:
[image: OutPut Gradient TextField]